# Connecting Chrome "Rich Notification" Api to Drop Down Menu

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to have it so that when a user clicks on the drop down menu in the google chrome's browser extension context menu that it creates the Chrome Notification. Any insight as to what I'm doing wrong would be much appreciated.

Side Note: All this is connected to a default popup on the chrome navbar that opens up a pop up box when clicked.

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
    var context = "selection";
    var title = "Add To test";
    var id = chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": title, "contexts":[context],
        "id": "context" + context});
});

var options = {
    type: "basic",
    title: "Primary Title",
    message: "Primary message to display",
    iconURL: "test_logo.png"
};

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function() {
    chrome.notifications.create(options, blarg);
});

function blarg() {
    console.log("Pop UP FOR LIFE");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var options = {
    type: "basic",
    title: "Primary Title",
    message: "Primary message to display",
    iconUrl: "test_logo.png"
};
```

You must change `iconURL` to `iconUrl`. After change notifications will [work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShT02.png).

[chrome.notifications](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/notifications#property-NotificationOptions-iconUrl) | [examples](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/richNotifications)

Comment: Thanks so much for answering, but I'm still getting this error: "Error in event handler for contextMenus: TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined".

Comment: You don't have appropriate permissions then. You need `"contextMenus"` and `"notifications"` in manifest permissions.

Comment: Thanks, that was it!